# Spring boot and hibernate validation failure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

I am using Hibernate with Spring Boot, and am simply validating the schema using the properties:

`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`

This works fine, the application fails to start up (error code 1) if validation against the database fails.

What I would like to do is to fail with a specific error code, so it can be handled.  I'd like to catch the SchemaManagementException somehow, but can't see how this can be done, as the validation seems to happen as the first thing, before beans are created.

Comment: Can you share the logs of your Spring application?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an issue with field naming for your schema, hack method to resolve your naming schemas:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```